# How to set up Client ID and Client Secret for adding Azure SQL as data source for Search & intelligence in Microsoft 365 admin center

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Go to Microsoft 365 admin center > Settings > [Search & intelligence](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/#/MicrosoftSearch) > Data sources, click "+ Add" to add a new data source, select Azure SQL and click Next, how to set up or where to get the Client ID and Client Secret?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an app registration on Microsoft Entra ID and then configure a secret and use the client ID and secret.

You can follow the guide below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/azure-ad-authentication-sql-server-setup-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver16#create-and-register-a-microsoft-entra-application

Comment: Thanks, after registering the app and set up the client secret, when click the "Test connection" button, I got "Error from database server: Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. The server is not currently configured to accept this token.".   I am trying to create the connector inside tenant A, but both the Azure SQL and new registered app are in tenant B. Do you think using two tenants in this way could be the reason for causing this error?

Comment: Yep @J.W, I would say so. If you are creating the connector in tenant A, then at least the app registration (which is a security principal and will be used by your connector) needs to be created in tenant A as well. I believe the database can stay in tenant B.

Comment: @J.W if you are good, can you please mark my reply as the response so we can close this question? Thanks

Comment: Hi Hugo, not really, I have tried setting up the app registration in tenant A, but still had the same error

Comment: @J.W sorry I just looked again to you message before, and I think by registering the app in tenant B would be better for you. Then you just need to create a user for that app in your DB, and assign the correct roles to that user

CREATE USER Microsoft_Entra_principal FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER  
    [ WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = schema_name ]  
[;]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#microsoft_entra_principal

Comment: EXEC sp_addrolemember [db_datareader], <app-user-id>;

Comment: Also, you need to ensure you don't have windows authentication enabled for this app user as per the documentation - "Microsoft Entra users can't have Windows Authentication logins in SQL Database;"